# Small USB drive with hardware write-protection switch

Tags: usb, flash-drive, encryption

I am currently looking for a USB stick with hardware write-protection that is small enough to fit in my keychain.

Searching the internet I could only find the [Kanguru SS3](https://www.kanguru.com/storage-accessories/kanguru-ss3.shtml), which has a slightly too large form factor.

Comment: What is your budget, and how big is too big?

Comment: Something like the [Kingston SE9](http://www.kingston.com/us/usb/personal_business/dtse9h) would be nice. It doesn't have to be cheap.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are no USB sticks with hardware write switch of such small form-factor as Kingston SE9 (*39mm* of length). There are some alternatives smaller (shorter) than Kanguru SS3.

- [**Kanguru FlashBlu30**](https://www.kanguru.com/storage-accessories/flashblu30-usb-flash-drive-with-physical-write-protect-switch.shtml) - *64mm* (8-64GB) / *71mm* (128-256GB)
- [**Netac U336**](http://www.netac.com/mini/378.html) - *67.5mm*
- [**Kanguru Defender 3000**](https://www.kanguru.com/secure-storage/defender-3000-usb-3-secure-hardware-encrypted-flash-drive.shtml) - *72.2mm*
- [Kanguru SS3](https://www.kanguru.com/storage-accessories/kanguru-ss3-high-performance-usb-flash-drive-with-physical-write-protect-switch.shtml) is long *77mm*

Some alternatives:

- searching for a small SD card USB reader
- there are smaller form-factor USB pendrives with customisable fingerprint protection